# how to get object value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have this object in my session

```
name: "test",
is_feature: "0",
attributes: [
  {
   '5': "blue"
  },
  {
   '7': "iOS"
  }
],
cost: "2000",
```

I want to use attributes in foreach.some thing like below code:

```
foreach ($product->attributes as $attribute){     
   ProductAttributeValue::create([
            'attribute_id' => $attribute->key,  //like 5,7
            'value' => $attribute->value  //like blue,iOS
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this loop**:

First you convert json to associative arrays like:

```
$productAttributes = json_decode($product->attributes, true);
```

and then

```
foreach ($productAttributes as $attributes) {
     foreach ($attributes as $key => $attribute) {
         ProductAttributeValue::create([
             'attribute_id' => $key,  // like 5,7
             'value' => $attribute  // like blue,iOS
         ]);
     }
}
```

I hope it would helpful.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Every item of `attributes` is a separate object.

Comment: @gulshan ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Trying to get property 'key' of non-object

Comment: show the output after you decode the json into array??

Comment: @mohammadHosseini can you put you complete json here?

Comment: Error: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Hey @mohammadHosseini show me the output of this :  `dd($product->attributes);`

Comment: @inzamam-idrees `array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "'1'" => "4"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "'2'" => "iOS"
  ]
]`

Comment: @Gulshan this is my laravel session and it's like json I think

Comment: @mohammadHosseini check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You use this:

```
$str = '{"name": "test", "is_feature": "0", "attributes": [{"5": "blue"},{"7": "iOS"}],"cost": "2000"}';
$arr = json_decode($str, true); // convert the string to associative array

foreach($arr["attributes"] as $attribute) {
    $key = key($attribute); // get the first key as "5" of "7"
    echo "key: $key and val: " . $attribute[$key]; // access the value as $attribute[$key] will give blue or ios
};
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/HZHTc)

Reference: [key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)

Comment: @mohammadHosseini You had twice `'` before the keys of 5 and 7. Chabge that to `"` (the `'` are used for string declaration you can use them inside)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for you.

```
$strArr = [
    'name'=>"test",
     'is_feature'=> "0",
     'attributes'=>[[5=> "blue"],[7=> "iOS"]],
     'cost'=> "2000"
];
$str = json_encode($strArr);
$arr = (array) json_decode($str);
$att = (array) $arr['attributes'];
foreach($att as  $val) {
    foreach($val as  $key=>$attributes) {
    echo "key: ".$key." and val: " . $attributes . PHP_EOL;
    }
};
```

Output:

```
key: 5 and val: blue
key: 7 and val: iOS
```

Hope this will help you